# What happens if both players die simultaneously?

Tags: hearthstone

If both players are very low health and someone plays this card:

[image: Hellfire]

Both players could die simultaneously. What happens in Arena when this event occurs? Does it count as a loss for both players? Does it count at all for your Arena record?

Side note: Holy Nova + Auchenai Soulpriest could cause the same scenario.

Comment: So could the paladin Eye for an Eye Secret.

Comment: Or Abomination death.

Comment: Or 'Ysera Awakens'.

Comment: Pretty sure Eye for an Eye wouldn't cause a tie b/c Death would be checked before the trigger is checked on the secret.  Similar to "State Based Actions" for those familiar with the finer points of Magic the Gathering rules.

Comment: I lost due to Eye for an Eye, they died then I died

Comment: Best tie I've ever seen: [Tavern Brawl](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/%27Servant_of_Yogg-Saron%27_Tryouts) where every minion drop casts a random spell, nothing interesting till turn 4, opponent drops [Auchenai Soulpriest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Auchenai_Soulpriest) and the random cast is... [Tree of Life](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tree_of_Life).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When two players die simultaneously, that counts as a tie even though it's displayed as a loss in the end screen. A tie will neither increase your number of wins nor your number of losses in Arena.

Ties will also not affect your rank in ranked play.

Comment: I guess that since TIE is a rare scenario this is the best way to deal with it (but i didnt like the loss screen in the end even if its better then saying you won and dont count as victory)

Comment: Source?  Also out of curiosity, is there a screenshot/video of what the game looks like when a tie occurs?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't have a screenshot or video, but it looks exactly the same as if you had lost. I don't have an official source, just personal experience and other people saying the same thing online.

Comment: In addition to dying simultaneously, a game that lasts 50 turns will also end in a tie.