# Can you tie in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm curious about some of the hearthstone rules, specifically about when the game is considered a tie.

So, for example, what happens in the following scenarios?

- If a warlock plays hellfire when both heroes are at 3hp or less.
- If your opponent has 5hp, and you have 3hp. You play a leper gnome, and then hellfire.

So, what happens in such occasions? A tie? Both opponents lose? or what else?

Comment: Agreed with Ken, if only because the answer to that question answers this question.

Comment: What about the Leper Gnome situation?

Comment: @GarretJ That is a seperate question, something along the lines of triggers resolving when one player has already died. Would recommend searching for/asking that as a seperate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a game can be a tie. This happens if both players are reduced to 0 health at the same time. It can also happen if the game lasts beyond a certain number of turns- 50 if I recall correctly- which is extremely rare as both players would need to survive the fatigue.

Certain server errors can disconnect both players simultaneously, which also causes a tie.

A tie is displayed as a loss to both players but **isn't actually counted as a loss**. This means that neither player will lose any rank and this will not count towards their three losses in arena.

Comment: @Shaeldon Stack Exchange is a wonderful site: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172544/what-happens-in-arena-if-both-players-die-simultaneously

Comment: Tis entirely possible this question should be marked as a duplicate of that question, due to the fact that the top answer to that question answers all of this one.

Comment: @Waterseas agree, flagged

Comment: An example of a 50-turn game is where both players play Mal'Ganis to gain immunity and keep passing.

Comment: @Waterseas Agreed, but I think the question title of that question should be changed so it's not arena-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

I was unable to found an official source but i'll leave you this [Link](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/general-discussion/11644-can-there-be-a-tie-game) from a good source.

When you do tie, it is shown as a **loss** for **both** players but does not count as one.

Comment: +1 can confirm, died from goblin bombs at the same time as my opponent and we both _lost_.

Comment: To be fair, this answer doesn't answer all the questions.

Comment: This is not entirely correct- see my answer.

Comment: Ties appear as losses for both players, but are not actually losses (they don't affect your rank nor Arena loss count).

Comment: @Tjd To be fair, they are two parts of the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a tie a player can die and come back to life in a single action. Example:
Paladin with 2 HP and TrueSilver Champion weapon equipped attacks a minion that does 3 damage. For a moment the paladin will appear to go to -1HP and then the heal from the sword will bring it back up to 1 HP.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. The heal effect of the sword goes off first at the beginning of the attack bringing the Paladin to 4 HP. Then running into the minion that does 3 will bring him down to 1. If it was the other way around he would simply lose because his health was below zero. Order of operations matter in this game.